# Generating plot before end of program in python

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot elements of two arrays against each other. Whilst the plot works fine, it does not generate the image before asking whether the user wants to continue or not.
(this code is embedded in a while true loop).

```
    print 'To achieve the million pound goal using your betting strategy, you would have to spin the wheel approximately',averageiterations, 'times on average.'
    print 'The theoretical probability of you obtaining a million based on your betting strategy is: %9.7e' % p
    print 'The approximate average total amount of times that you ran out of money while using your betting strategy (went below the minimum bet) is:',len(fails)/1000.,', which rounds up to', int(math.ceil(len(fails)/1000.)),'.'

i=0
millions=[]
millionspins=[]
while i<1000:
    millions.append(allnewbank[:][i][-1])
    i=i+1
i=0
while i<1000:
    millionspins.append(len(allnewbank[:][i]))
    i=i+1
fig = plt.figure()
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(millionspins,millions)
plt.xlabel("Number of spins")
plt.ylabel("Bank")
plt.xlim(0,max(millionspins))
plt.ylim(1000000,max(millions))
plt.show()
while restart not in exit:
        restart=raw_input('Please type "y" to restart or "n" to exit:')
    if restart==exit[0]:
            continue    
    if restart==exit[1]:
        break
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be helpful if you could include a complete, minimal **working** example of your code. The is a lot of information that is not essential (such as the `x,ylables) and your code does not run as listed (what is 'allnewbank'?).

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to see where the program is asking for user input.  I think what you're asking, though, is how to display a plot and continue with the program?  If so, you can simply disable matplotlib from blocking the program:

```
plt.show(block = False)
```

Comment: Hey, I've tried that and it returns "show() got an unexpected keyword argument 'block'"

Comment: So it seems that `block` is experimental - didn't realize that.  An alternative is to use `plt.ion()` to turn on interactive mode before you start plotting.  But I would look into it further as I don't know if it affects anything else.